# vectorization of framewise Binary accuracy calculation

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am working of customizing the standard model.fit() method to calculate frame-wise accuracy of each sample during validation. Sample dimension is 512 time frames and 128 frequency bins. As of now I am calculating frame wise binary accuracy by looping through each frame of the sample but this is taking more time (~ 7 seconds per sample). Due to which validation process takes lot of time. How can I speedup the process by vectorizing the process or by other methods?

Sample code I am using is as below:

```
def test_step(self, data):
    x, y = data # Unpack the data   x: (8, 512, 128, 1)    y: (8, 512, 6)

    for spl in tf.range(1 if tf.shape(x)[0] == None else tf.shape(x)[0]):
        val_accuracy_frm = tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy(name='frame_accuracy')
        val_accuracy_frm_auc = tf.keras.metrics.AUC(name='AUC_accuracy')
        x_spl = tf.reshape(x[spl], (1, tf.shape(x)[1], tf.shape(x)[2], tf.shape(x)[3]))

        y_pred = self(x_spl, training=False) # y_pred : ([4], 1,512, 6)


        for frame in tf.range(tf.shape(x)[1]):
            for scl in ['8', '4', '2', '1']:  # Note: For ease, '8' is always the smallest resolution scale and is at index 0 (always) followed by '4' --> '2' --> '1'
                if scl == '8':
                    val_accuracy_frm.reset_states()
                    val_accuracy_frm.update_state(y[spl][frame], y_pred[0][0][frame])
                    accuracy_8 = val_accuracy_frm.result()
                    val_accuracy_frm.reset_states()

                elif scl == '4':
                    val_accuracy_frm.reset_states()
                    val_accuracy_frm.update_state(y[spl][frame], y_pred[1][0][frame])
                    accuracy_4 = val_accuracy_frm.result()
                    val_accuracy_frm.reset_states()

                elif scl == '2':
                    val_accuracy_frm.reset_states()
                    val_accuracy_frm.update_state(y[spl][frame], y_pred[2][0][frame])
                    accuracy_2 = val_accuracy_frm.result()
                    val_accuracy_frm.reset_states()

                elif scl == '1':
                    val_accuracy_frm.reset_states()
                    val_accuracy_frm.update_state(y[spl][frame], y_pred[3][0][frame])
                    accuracy_1 = val_accuracy_frm.result()
                    val_accuracy_frm.reset_states()


            val_acc['a8'] = tf.reduce_mean((val_acc['a8'], float(accuracy_8)))
            val_acc['a4'] = tf.reduce_mean((val_acc['a4'], float(accuracy_4)))
            val_acc['a2'] = tf.reduce_mean((val_acc['a2'], float(accuracy_2)))
            val_acc['a1'] = tf.reduce_mean((val_acc['a1'], float(accuracy_1)))


    # bce_loss(y, y_pred) # Updates the metrics tracking the loss
    val_loss_avg.update_state(y, y_pred) # Update the metrics.
    val_accuracy.update_state(y, y_pred) # Update the metrics.

    return {m.name: m.result() for m in [val_loss_avg, val_accuracy]}
```

I am using a 4-output model, batch size is 8, and total Labels are 6.

Comment: What is taking the time?  If you're going to do performance analysis, you'll have to instrument your code by inserting time hacks before and after the major steps.  Otherwise, it's very easy to waste your time optimizing sections that don't matter.

Comment: @TimRoberts I did put time stamps before and after the for loop (for frame in tf.range(tf.shape(x)[1])) and after calculating the difference between these time stamps it gives me around 7.5 seconds per iteration of the loop. Which means it takes 7.5 seconds to process 1 sample = 512 time frames.

Comment: That doesn't tell you what's taking the time.  Is it the `metrics.AUC` call?  Is it the `update_state` call?  Is it the `reduce_mean` calls?  You need these details.

Comment: And what does `y_pred = self(x_spl, training=false)` do?  Is there a method name missing?

Comment: @TimRoberts** y_pred = self(x_spl, training=false)** is model.predict(x_spl, training=false) and is adapted from https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/customizing_what_happens_in_fit

Also, I am not using **metrics.AUC** its just instantiated.
I think **update_state** is taking time as it will be calculating accuracy before updating the metric.

Comment: I get it; they got cute and overrode `__call__` for that.  You are probably right with the timing, but you really should measure them all individually so you KNOW.  There's nothing more painful than optimizing a chunk of code and then learning it wasn't your pain point after all.  Take the time once to measure it.

Comment: I assume you're able to put full `x` through the model? What then is the shape of `y_pred`? Is it `(8, 4, 1, 512, 6)`?

Comment: Oh I guess it's a 4-tuple where each element has shape `(8, 512, 6)`?

Comment: @AaronKeesing Yes, you are right. 4 is the no of outputs in the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `y_pred` is a 4-tuple where each `y_pred[i]` has shape `(8, 512, 6)` like `y`, I think you can do something like this:

```py
def test_step(self, data):
    x, y = data  # Unpack the data   x: (8, 512, 128, 1)    y: (8, 512, 6)
    y_pred = self(x, training=False)  # shape ([4], 8, 512, 6)
    val_acc = {}
    for key, idx in zip(["a8", "a4", "a2", "a1"], range(4)):
        val_acc[key] = tf.keras.metrics.binary_accuracy(y, y_pred[idx])  # shape (8, 512)
    val_acc = {k: tf.reduce_mean(val_acc[k]) for k in val_acc}

    # ...
```

`val_acc` is then a `dict` of mean accuracies for each of a8, a4, a2, a1 across the whole batch, which you can use for whatever.

**EDIT**: If you want per-frame metrics just remove the final line with `reduce_mean`.

Comment: This solution seems to be working but on sample level. I wants to calculate the accuracy for each 512 time frames of the sample. Though, replacing the '''val_accuracy_frm.update_state(y[spl][frame], y_pred[][][frame])''' with the one suggested by you has helped a lot to fine tune the validation time for 1 epoch. Earlier it was taking roughly 30 min for each epoch validation run, but now it takes roughly 7 min. I wants to bring it down to around 2-3 minutes as there are only 200 samples in validation data.

Comment: I've updated my answer. I doubt you can make it that  much faster. How much time does it take to put everything through the model?